# INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-insert, chave-estrangeira

Estou com um problema ao realizar INSERT em uma tabela no meu BD pois sempre que tento realizar o INSERT o SQL Server me retornar isso :

A instrução INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY "FK_PEDIDO". O conflito ocorreu no banco de dados "Empresa", tabela "dbo.PEDIDO", column 'COD_PEDIDO'.

Já li as query varias vezes e mesmo assim nao encontro meu erro, seguem as query das tables envolvidas :

Table PEDIDO

```
-- Criando tabela PEDIDO
CREATE TABLE PEDIDO

(COD_PEDIDO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1001,1),

DATA_VENDA DATE NOT NULL,

COD_CLIENTE INT NOT NULL,

COD_VENDEDOR INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT FK_VENDEDOR FOREIGN KEY (COD_VENDEDOR) REFERENCES VENDEDOR

(COD_VENDEDOR),

CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE FOREIGN KEY (COD_CLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTE

(COD_CLIENTE));

-- Inserindo dados na tabela PEDIDO

INSERT INTO PEDIDO

VALUES

    ('2019/11/15', 1, 12),

    ('2019/11/10', 2, 12),

    ('2019/11/20', 3, 11),

    ('2019/11/22', 3, 13),

    ('2019/11/20', 4, 14),

    ('2019/11/25', 2, 10);


Table ITEM_PEDIDO

-- Criando tabela

CREATE TABLE ITEM_PEDIDO(

COD_ITEM INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (200,1),

COD_PEDIDO INT NOT NULL,

COD_PROD INT NOT NULL,

QTDE_VENDIDO INT NOT NULL,

PRECO_VENDA FLOAT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUTO FOREIGN KEY (COD_PROD) REFERENCES PRODUTO (COD_PROD),

CONSTRAINT FK_PEDIDO FOREIGN KEY (COD_PEDIDO) REFERENCES PEDIDO (COD_PEDIDO));


--Inserindo dados na tabela Item_Pedido
INSERT INTO ITEM_PEDIDO

VALUES

    (1048, 100, 1, 2500.00),

    (1044, 101, 1, 1500.00),

    (1045, 102, 1, 1500.00),

    (1046, 103, 1, 300.00),

    (1047, 104, 1, 700.00);
```

Att

Comment: Os registros de cod_pedido 1048, 1044, 1045, 1046 e 1047 existem na tabela pedido? Você provavelmente está lidando com esses erros porque está referenciando um item do seu pedido pra um pedido não existente...

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro ocorre porque você está tentando inserir um registro na tabela **ITEM_PEDIDO** com o `COD_PEDIDO`: 1048, 1044, 1045, 1046 e 1047, porém eles não existem na tabela **PEDIDO**, impossibilitando o banco de dados de fazer referência entre as duas tabelas, pois sua foreign key espera um registro existente da tabela **PEDIDO**.

Verifique se estes `COD_PEDIDO` realmente existem na tabela **PEDIDO**:

```
SELECT * FROM PEDIDO
```

Basta passar pra sua query de `INSERT ITEM_PEDIDO` código de pedidos existentes na tabela **PEDIDO** que tudo ocorrerá conforme o esperado.